# Logical operator Python

Tags: python, operators, nonetype

Probably a very basic question but I can not solve this.

That's my code:

```
if type(lines_r).__name__ == 'NoneType' or type(lines_l).__name__ == 'NoneType':
no_detected.append(i)
else: ...
```

Now, I don't want to use and/or operators because in this case I just want:

- if the first condition is true <(lines_r) == Nonetype> so it'll be -No.detected- and, not connected to the other condition, I want to do the same thing for the other one (lines_l).

Because the 2 conditions could be not related in time (they are not at the same time both true or both false so I can't use AND + if I use OR then the condition is true if only one of the two is NoneType, and that's not what I want).
[The variables are str]

What's the best way to write this?

*EDIT
That's the things that I'm calculating

```
lines_r = cv2.HoughLinesP(Ske_conn_right[i],
                            rho = 1, 
                            theta =np.pi/180, 
                            threshold = 4, 
                            minLineLength=2,
                            maxLineGap=7)
    lines_l = cv2.HoughLinesP(Ske_conn_left[i],
                            rho = 1, 
                            theta =np.pi/180, 
                            threshold = 4, 
                            minLineLength=2,
                            maxLineGap=7)
```

I'm doing detection of moving objects in a video. The results are arrays that could have some 0 values (in a simplistic way where objects are not detected).

lines_l or lines_r could result in a Nonetype obj

Comment: Why are you looking at the `__name__` attribute at all? Use `instanceof` to check the type of your objects.

Comment: Why don't you just check against `is None`?

Comment: because the thing that I'm calculating is a NumPy array that could result in some NoneType values

Comment: Have I understood your question correctly: You want to append to `no_detected` if `lines_r is None`. You also want to append to `no_detected` if `lines_l is None`.  That _is_ the boolean `or` operator. Maybe add some detail to your [mre] to clarify the problem?

Comment: Your shouldn't have `NoneType` in arrays in the first place. That means you're working with an `object` type and you should be using lists, because numpy will buy you nothing here

Comment: Why are you doing this: `type(lines_r).__name__ == 'NoneType'`? generally to see if something is none, you use `if lines_r is None`, and if you want to check the *type* of something, e.g. see if it is a `dict` you do `isinstance(x, dict)` or `type(x) is dict`

Comment: I don't know why but when I use OR (as I thought I would) if it doesn't find one object, then it will not display the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to check if a value has a particular type, but here you should simply check if the value is `None`:

```
if lines_r is None or lines_l is None:
    no_detected.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

if both of your conditions are not related maybe you could use a if and else if statement

```
if type(lines_r).__name__ == 'NoneType':
      no_detected.append(i)
elif type(lines_l).__name__ == 'NoneType':
      no_detected.append(i)
else: ...
```

Then again that's the same thing as using an or statement, but it's just more similar to how you explained your logic

Answer (score 1):

If you want the condition to be true only if one of `line_r` and `line_l` is `None`, you can test the variables first and then test if the results are not equal:

```
if (lines_r is None) != (lines_l is None):
    no_detected.append(i)
```